# $|f|^2$ is complex differentiable at $z$ iff $f(z) = 0$ or $f'(z) = 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Given: $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic.
Prove that the function $|f|^2$ is complex differentiable at $z$ if and only if $f(z) = 0$ or $f'(z) = 0$.

Showing $"\leftarrow"$ is easy.

$"\rightarrow"$
$|f|^2$ is complex differentiable at $z$.
Let $z=x+iy=(x,y)$ and $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+i v(x,y)$. Because $f$ is holomorphic, $u$ and $v$ are real differentiable for all $(x,y)$ and the Cauchy-Riemann-equations are satisfied.

$|f(x,y)|^2=u^2(x,y)+v^2(x,y)$. Because $|f(x,y)|^2$ is complex differentiable in $(x,y)$ the C-R-equations are satisfied with:

$I)\, u(x,y)\,u_x(x,y)+v(x,y)\,v_x(x,y)=0$

$II)\,u(x,y)\,u_y(x,y)+v(x,y)\,v_y(x,y)=0$

And I also know that: $\frac{d|f|^2}{dz}(z)=u(x,y)\,u_x(x,y)+v(x,y)\,v_x(x,y)=0$.

How can I conclude now that $f(z) = 0$ or $f'(z) = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
 f(z) \overline{f'(z)} &= (u(x,y)+iv(x, y)) (u_x(x, y)-iv_x(x, y)) \\
 &= \bigl((u(x, y)u_x(x, y)+v(x, y)v_x(x, y)\bigr) \\
 & \quad + i \bigl(-(u(x, y)v_x(x, y)+v(x, y)u_x(x, y)\bigr) \\
& = \bigl((u(x, y)u_x(x, y)+v(x, y)v_x(x, y)\bigr) \\
& \quad + i \bigl((u(x, y)u_y(x, y)+v(x, y)v_y(x, y)\bigr) 
\end{align}
$$
is zero exactly if the CR equations (I) and (II) for $|f|^2$ are satisfied. Therefore is
$$
 |f|^2 \text{ complex differentiable at } z \\
\iff  f(z) \overline{f'(z)} = 0 \\
\iff f(z) = 0 \text{ or } f'(z) = 0 \, .
$$

---

Using [Wirtinger derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives) one can also calculate
$$
 \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} |f|^2 
= \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} (f \bar f)
= (\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} f) \bar f + f (\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} \bar f) = f \cdot \overline{f'}
$$
because $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} f = 0$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z} \bar f = \overline{\frac{\partial}{\partial  z}  f} = \overline{f'}$, from which the equivalence also follows.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f'(z)=(u_x,v_x)\neq 0$. The fact that $f$ is holomorphic tells you, by CR, that $(u_x,v_x)$ and $(u_y,v_y)$ are orthogonal vectors in the plane. Then, your equations I and II imply that the vector $f(z)=(u,v)$ is orthogonal to both of them, so it must be trivial. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $f$ is (complex) differentiable at $z$. We have:

$$\frac{f(z+h) \bar f(z+h)- f(z) \bar f(z)}{h}= \frac{(f(z+h)- f(z)) \bar f(z+h) + f(z)(\bar f(z+h) - \bar f(z))}{h}= \bar f(z+h) \cdot \frac{f(z+h) - f(z)}{h} + f(z)\cdot \frac{\bar f(z+h) - \bar f(z)}{\bar h}\cdot \frac{\bar h}{h}$$

As $h\to 0 $  the first term above converges to $\bar f(z) \cdot f'(z)$,  the second term has a limit  if an only if $f(z) \cdot \bar f'(z) = 0$, due to the behaviour of $\frac{\bar h}{h}\ $.